# Why is smbtree asking for a password?

Tags: samba

I have three computers; one CentOS 7 and two Fedora 30. All of them have identical Samba configurations (except shares).

On the CentOS and one Fedora machine I can `smbtree` without a password prompt on both root and unprivileged users. But on the other Fedora machine I get a password prompt for both root and unprivileged users.

Why am I getting a password prompt at all for querying my local workgroup?

I'm aware that I can pass `--no-pass`. This question is specifically asking why I receive a different prompt for this one machine.

Comment: Please check whether `ls -l \`which smbtree\`` looks the same on all machines, and post the output.

Comment: It's `-rwxr-xr-x root:root /usr/bin/smbtree` on all machines.

Comment: `smbtree` opens the files `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and `/etc/krb5.conf` as well as `/etc/krb5.conf.d/*`. Please compare these files on the two Fedora machines.

Comment: They are identical: https://pastebin.com/E5uCaXQi